# proguard AssembleRelease errors

Tags: android, proguard

I have upgraded my project to the actual Android build environment. Before it was working. Now I get errors in gradele assembleRelease. 
In the log I get lot of notes and then 2 warnings which I think lead to the failure.
My problem is now that I have no information what 10 unresolved references to classes or interfaces or  5 instances of library classes depending on program classes are meant.

```
Note: there were 1 library classes explicitly being kept.
      You don't need to keep library classes; they are already left unchanged.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#libraryclass)
Note: there were 25 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces.
      You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclass)
Warning: there were 10 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
Warning: there were 5 instances of library classes depending on program classes.
         You must avoid such dependencies, since the program classes will
         be processed, while the library classes will remain unchanged.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dependency)
Warning: Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
Thread(Tasks limiter_1): destruction

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':myapp:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> Job failed, see logs for details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 34s
237 actionable tasks: 236 executed, 1 up-to-date
```